# Cisco SG-300 10 Port Vlans

Tags: cisco

I'm not sure what i'am doing wrong, but when i add a vlan, i can not join a vlan on a selected port because the box is empty. I had trouble before with a SG-300 52 port, but somehow cant get this baby switch to see the vlan 1 and vlan 999.

Also to add to this, If i manually set up vlans via the interface settings. Traffic does not pass through.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was the firmware needed updating, i found there to be quite a few issues with the firmware that was installed.